# How to send an email with an attachment from Play! Framework 1.2.4

Tags: java, playframework, apache-commons-email

Trying to get Play! Framework to send an email with an attachment.  Code below works fine if I don't add the attachment to the message.  I've tried both with Play's Mailer class and with the Apache Commons classes (as below), but in both cases, the page just sits there with a spinner (Chrome) and no email is received.

```
EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
attachment.setURL(new URL(base + "public/images/triangles.png"));
attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
attachment.setDescription("test");
attachment.setName("test");

emailaddress = "test@test.com";

MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setDebug(true);
email.addTo(emailaddress);
email.setFrom("Testing <test@test.com>");
email.setSubject("Testing email");
try
{
    email.attach(attachment);
}
catch (EmailException ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
email.setMsg("test email");
email.send();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im guessing you've already had a look at the [Examples for Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html) and [Sending e-mail - Play! Framework 1.1](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/emails)?

IMO I'd suggest using a well known library with loads of documentation and examples like [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) and their [api](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html).

Here are a few tutorials that will get you started immediately:

- [JavaMail quick start](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2001/jw-1026-javamail.html)
- [Java Mail SMTPClient Example](http://www.roseindia.net/javamail/SMTPClient.shtml)
- [Sending mail with attachment with javamail](http://home-1.worldonline.nl/~bmc88/java/sbook/043.html)

An example of using the JavaMail to send a Email with attachment via gmail is:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String username = "username@gmail.com";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        // Define message
        MimeMessage message =
                new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(
                new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject(
                "Hello JavaMail Attachment");

        // create the message part 
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart =
                new MimeBodyPart();

        //fill message
        messageBodyPart.setText("Hi");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Part two is attachment
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source =
                new FileDataSource(fileAttachment);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(
                new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileAttachment);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send the message
        Transport.send(message);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

HTH

**References:**

- [JavaMail API – Sending Email Via Gmail SMTP Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)
- http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=30251

Comment: Issue is turning out to be a problem in generating the attachment correctly in the first place - it works fine from a browser or cURL request, just not when trying to pull it into a bytearray.  Since your answer is helpful and accurate for the original question, I'm going to mark it accepted.